# complex Xpath into Linq to XML

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My input XML:

```
....
    <node Attribute1 = "GUID1">
        <childnode1 AttributeChildnode= var1> </childnode>
        <childnode2 AttributeChildnode= var2> </childnode>
    </node>
    <node Attribute1 = "GUID2">
        <childnode3 AttributeChildnode= var3> </childnode>
        <childnode4 AttributeChildnode= var4> </childnode>
    </node>
....
```

my XPath code looks like this

```
mynodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes(".//node[@Attribute1 ='" & varString1 &'']/nodechild[@AttributeChildnode1 = ''& varString2 &'']")
```

I have no Idea how the Linq to XML code should look like to get the same result
can somebody please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can still use XPath using `XDocument` and LINQ to XML;

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var myNodeList = doc.XPathSelectElements(".//node[@Attribute1 ='" & varString1 &'']/nodechild[@AttributeChildnode1 = ''& varString2 &'']");
```

`XPathSelectElements` is declared as Extension Method on `XNode`, within `System.Xml.XPath` namespace.

***Standard*** Linq to XML version

Input XML:

```
<root>
    <node Attribute1="GUID1">
        <childnode AttributeChildNode1="var1" AttributeChildNode2="result1"></childnode>
        <childnode AttributeChildNode1="var2" AttributeChildNode2="result2"></childnode>
    </node>
    <node Attribute1="GUID2">
        <childnode AttributeChildNode1="var3" AttributeChildNode2="result3"></childnode>
        <childnode AttributeChildNode1="var4" AttributeChildNode2="result4"></childnode>
    </node>
</root>
```

Query:

```
string guid = "GUID1";
string var = "var1";

var elements = XElement.Load("Input.txt");

var value = (from node in elements.Elements("node")
             where (string)node.Attribute("Attribute1") == "GUID1"
             from childNode in node.Elements()
             where (string)childNode.Attribute("AttributeChildNode1") == "var1"
             select (string)childNode.Attribute("AttributeChildNode2")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Returns `result1` - `result4`, depending on `guid` and `var` variables values.

Comment: Is it also possible to do it without XpathSelectElements ? e.x.

dim var as IEnumerable( of Xelement) 
var = Select dummy from .............. Where ..... select dummy

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, but could you post input XML and desired output?

Comment: Input

 
`code
     ....

      <node Attribute1 = "GUID1"> 
        <childnode1 AttributeChildnode= var1> </childnode>
        <childnode2 AttributeChildnode= var2> </childnode>
        </node>
    <node Attribute1 = "GUID2"> 
        <childnode3 AttributeChildnode= var3> </childnode>
        <childnode4 AttributeChildnode= var4> </childnode>
        </node>
         ....
`
desired Output could be var1,var2,var3 or var4 based on the users choice. Sorry for not being able to format text correct